# Taking API response and adding it to json, AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, list, api, dictionary

I am making an API request and want to add the response to a JSON. Then subsequent request responses adding to the same JSON file.

I have separated out the block of code that isn't working, adding just one API call and dealing with the request. The issue is I cannot write the JSON file with this info. When trying I get the error "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'" I, therefore, presumed my result from the API request is a dictionary. I then tried, in about 4 ways, to convert this into a list to allow the append. Obviously, none of these methods worked.

```
import json
import requests

fname = "NewdataTest.json"

request_API = requests.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/745?api_key=***")
print(request_API)
# Check Reponse from API
#print(request_API.json())
newData = (request_API.json())

# function to add to JSON
def write_json(data, fname):
    with open(fname, "w") as f:
              json.dump(data, f, indent = 4)

with open (fname) as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    temp = data[0]
    #print(newData) 
    y = newData
    temp.append(y)
    
write_json(data)
```

JSON I am trying to add data too

```
[
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/e1cC9muSRtAHVtF5GJtKAfATYIT.jpg",
        "belongs_to_collection": null,
        "budget": 0,
        "genres": [
            {
                "id": 10749,
                "name": "Romance"
            },
            {
                "id": 35,
                "name": "Comedy"
            }
        ],
        "homepage": "",
        "id": 1063242,
        "imdb_id": "tt24640474",
        "original_language": "fr",
        "original_title": "Disconnect: The Wedding Planner",
        "overview": "After falling victim to a scam, a desperate man races the clock as he attempts to plan a luxurious destination wedding for an important investor.",
        "popularity": 34.201,
        "poster_path": "/tGmCxGkVMOqig2TrbXAsE9dOVvX.jpg",
        "production_companies": [],
        "production_countries": [
            {
                "iso_3166_1": "KE",
                "name": "Kenya"
            },
            {
                "iso_3166_1": "NG",
                "name": "Nigeria"
            }
        ],
        "release_date": "2023-01-13",
        "revenue": 0,
        "runtime": 107,
        "spoken_languages": [
            {
                "english_name": "English",
                "iso_639_1": "en",
                "name": "English"
            },
            {
                "english_name": "Afrikaans",
                "iso_639_1": "af",
                "name": "Afrikaans"
            }
        ],
        "status": "Released",
        "tagline": "",
        "title": "Disconnect: The Wedding Planner",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 5.8,
        "vote_count": 3
    }
]
```

Example of print(request_API.json())

```
{'adult': False, 'backdrop_path': '/paUKxrbN2ww0JeT2JtvgAuaGlPf.jpg', 'belongs_to_collection': None, 'budget': 40000000, 'genres': [{'id': 9648, 'name': 'Mystery'}, {'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}], 'homepage': '', 'id': 745, 'imdb_id': 'tt0167404', 'original_language': 'en', 'original_title': 'The Sixth Sense', 'overview': 'Following an unexpected tragedy, a child psychologist named Malcolm Crowe meets an nine year old boy named Cole Sear, who is hiding a dark secret.', 'popularity': 32.495, 'poster_path': '/4AfSDjjCy6T5LA1TMz0Lh2HlpRh.jpg', 'production_companies': [{'id': 158, 'logo_path': '/jSj8E9Q5D0Y59IVfYFeBnfYl1uB.png', 'name': 'Spyglass Entertainment', 'origin_country': 'US'}, {'id': 862, 'logo_path': '/udTjbqPmcTbfrihMuLtLcizDEM1.png', 'name': 'The Kennedy/Marshall Company', 'origin_country': 'US'}, {'id': 915, 'logo_path': '/4neXXpjSJDZPBGBnfWtqysB5htV.png', 'name': 'Hollywood Pictures', 'origin_country': 'US'}, {'id': 17032, 'logo_path': None, 'name': 'Barry Mendel Productions', 'origin_country': 'US'}], 'production_countries': [{'iso_3166_1': 'US', 'name': 'United States of America'}], 'release_date': '1999-08-06', 'revenue': 672806292, 'runtime': 107, 'spoken_languages': [{'english_name': 'Latin', 'iso_639_1': 'la', 'name': 'Latin'}, {'english_name': 'Spanish', 'iso_639_1': 'es', 'name': 'Español'}, {'english_name': 'English', 'iso_639_1': 'en', 'name': 'English'}], 'status': 'Released', 'tagline': 'Not every gift is a blessing.', 'title': 'The Sixth Sense', 'video': False, 'vote_average': 7.94, 'vote_count': 10125}
```

Comment: your json file contains an array of objects `[{...}]`, so `data` is an array of objects and `data[0]` is an object. What would you expect `someobject.append(someotherobject)` to do? You probably want to do `data.append(y)`

Comment: When I change temp.append(y) to data.append(y) I get TypeError: write_json() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fname' This confuses me as I'm using fname as a variable in the parameter to open the json?

Comment: you define your `def write_json(data, fname):` funciton to take two parameters. But when calling it like `write_json(data)` you are only passing one parameter. This error occured only after you have fixed the previous one. Because as long as the `append` was throwing an error, it didn't even reach the `write_json` so it had no chance to throw an error there ...

Comment: BTW defining a global `fname` variable and a local function parameter with the same name is not particulary good coding style, because -- like in your case -- it leads to major confusion. In your case you can just change the definition to `def write_json(data):` because it will already know the `fname` from the outer scope ...

Comment: Thanks. I added the variable into the function to make it clearer. Adding fname wrote to the json as expected thanks! I don't know how to mark this question as answered by yourself as it's in the comments. But thanks again

Comment: I posted my comments as an answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code

1. Your json file contains an array of objects `[{...}]`, so `data` is an array of objects and `data[0]` is an object. What would you expect `someobject.append(someotherobject)` to do? You probably want to do `data.append(y)`
2. You define your `def write_json(data, fname):` function to take two parameters. But when calling it like `write_json(data)` you are only passing one parameter.

The second error occured only after you have fixed the previous one. Because as long as the `append` was throwing an error, it didn't even reach the `write_json` so it had no chance to throw an error there ...